# How to get certain parts of a perl hash

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

I'm learning perl and using [Weather::NOAA::Alert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Weather%3a%3aNOAA%3a%3aAlert) and am wanting to figure out how to capture only a certain part of its output.

It outputs a hash, but I only want a certain part, for example the urgency part... what should I do?

[Sample output](http://warningweather.com/test.txt)

Comment: Perhaps you should post some sample code and output, so that we don't have to look up the documentation looking for things that outputs arrays?

Comment: That's not an array, that's a hash. You can loop through the keys with `for my $key (keys %$hashref) { print Dumper $hashref->{$key} ...` Rinse and repeat until you know how to reach the value you seek

Comment: @TLP - the url part of the hash is random... is there a way to compensate for that?

Comment: I doubt its "random". No matter what it is, you can access it with the `keys` function. Just nest loops.

Comment: @ZacharyLassiter - which specific hash are you trying to access? E.g. what's the **logic** you're trying to implement in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not array is a hash of hashes of hashes. You can access values by

```
$result->{'US'}->{'http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=MT124CAB8F109C.WinterWeatherAdvisory.124CAB90FBA0MT.TFXWSWTFX.c906fc319cc9f5b747e95ac455f8c2f0'}->{'certainty'}
```

will contain the string

```
Likely
```

Check http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/ for an introduction on Perl hashes.

Comment: this is along the right path but the URL part of its random... how do I compensate for randomness?  Are wildcards an option?

Comment: As as I said you should read about Perl hashes but in any case you can use the `keys` function to retrieve all the keys of an hash: `keys $result->{'US'}` will list you all the keys.